# Why can't my controller find my service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controllers

I keep getting the "Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider" when running this code. I have looked at a lot of other answers similar to this problem but just can't see where the error is.

Also, am I calling this service correctly with "myService()"?

I am relatively new to Angular, so any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My Service

```
angular.module('APP')

  .service('myService', ['$scope' function($scope) {

    $scope.search = {};

    $scope.resetFilters = function () {
        // needs to be a function or it won't trigger a $watch
        $scope.search = {};
    };

    // pagination controls
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.videos.length;
    $scope.entryLimit = 5; // videos per page
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

    // $watch search to update pagination
    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.videos, newVal);
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    }, true);

}]);
```

My Controller

```
angular.module('APP')

  .filter('startFrom', function () {
      return function (input, start) {
          if (input) {
              start = +start;
              return input.slice(start);
          }
          return [];
      };
  })

  .controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'filterFilter', 'myService', function ($scope, $http, filterFilter, myService) {

    $http.get("js/science.php")
      .success(function(data){
          $scope.videos = data;

          myService();
      })
      .error(function() {
          $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });

}]);
```

My Links

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>

<!-- CDN's and API's-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="controllers/myService.js"></script>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<script src="js/ui-router-title.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-youtube-embed.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/dbCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/scienceCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/politicsCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/pageCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/tabsCtrl.js"></script>
 <script src="controllers/modalCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: for a start, you can't inject `$scope` into a service.  Please review docs and tutorials on what the roles of $scope, controllers, and services are.  You also need to initialize/declare the 'APP' module at some point by using `angular.module('APP', []);` - notice the `[]` - this is the array where you list any other modules that your's depends on.  having this second argument is also what tells `angular.module` that you are declaring a new module (vs retrieving an existing one to extend it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I should have mentioned, I have a main app file where I have declared my app dependencies using `angular.module('APP', []);` As far as not being able to inject $scope into a service, I am really just trying to take the pagination code and make it reusable. Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? Thanks for the quick reply by the way.

Here is the original controller with the pagination code I want to make reusable.

```
angular.module('APP')

  .filter('startFrom', function () {
      return function (input, start) {
          if (input) {
              start = +start;
              return input.slice(start);
          }
          return [];
      };
  })

  .controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'filterFilter', function ($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

    // Link to PHP for mySQL content
    $http.get("js/science.php")
      .success(function(data){
        $scope.videos = data; // Array named 'data'

        // FROM HERE
        //=====================
        $scope.search = {};

        $scope.resetFilters = function () {
            // needs to be a function or it won't trigger a $watch
            $scope.search = {};
        };

        // pagination controls
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.videos.length;
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; // videos per page
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

        // $watch search to update pagination
        $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.videos, newVal);
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        }, true);
        // TO HERE REUSABLE
        //=====================

        })

      .error(function() {
          $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });

}]);
```